# Pushing contacts to Users' Phone Contacts (Exchange Server 2007)

Tags: exchange-server, contacts

We have users in our company that have smart phones (Android/Windows Phone mix)and put their contacts in their Exchange account. It is a unified group of users that just need the phone numbers for each other (with a considerably high turnaround for employees in this position as well). I am looking to get a list of contact names/phone numbers to be automatically pushed to (and updated, if possible) their Exchange contact lists. Previously we have been logging in with their account into a computer, opening Outlook, then loading a csv with the contacts on there. The issue is how time consuming it is, given that amount of turnaround on those users. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To create a Contact in a users Mailbox you will need access to that contacts folder in that mailbox so you either need to create a Service Account and give that account rights to the folder via something like Add-MailboxFolderPermission or get the user to delegate the access themselves if they are sensitive to security changes or use EWS impersonation.

Once you have rights to the users Contacts folder then you could automate the process of the CSV import using EWS and Powershell here are a few sample scripts

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Using-Powershell-to-import-14bef4b8

http://blogs.technet.com/b/bill_long/archive/2010/04/23/importing-public-folder-contacts-from-a-csv-file.aspx

http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2010/04/flexible-exchange-contact-creation.html

Cheers
Glen